# Links in R help files in VSCode not working

Tags: r, visual-studio-code

I am using the R extension for VSCode. When running ?function I can pull up a help file. In Rstudio I can follow hyperlinks in a help file to documentation to related functions. The links in VSCode do not work - clicking on them does nothing. How can I configure these links to work?

[image]

I've scoured the help and github pages for the R extension for VSCode and stackoverflow, couldn't find a similar question.